# Using bash profile for scp causes no such file error

Tags: scp, bash

I have a function in my `~/.bash_profile` file that looks like this:

```
scd() { scp username@host:$1 $2; }
```

I would like to use this to `scp` a file whose path is specified by `$1` to the path on my local machine specified by `$2`. The remote host will always be the same. However, when I run `scd path/to/remote/file local_file`, I get the following error:

```
local_file: No such file or directory
```

When I redefine the function as `scd() { scp username@host:path/to/remote/file $1; }` and run `scd local_file`, it works fine, so there must be some minor detail preventing this.

Thanks for your help.

Edit: I have been running this function from a local log directory, passing it the parameters `logs/sep21.log` as the remote path and `sep21.log` as the local filename.

Comment: Does the remote path contain spaces?

Comment: Please show the exact command you run that produces the error; the actual paths you provide are probably relevant.

Comment: I added the actual paths to the post.

Comment: And `logs` is a directory in the user's home directory?

Answer (score 2):

Try quoting your variables..

```
scd() { scp username@host:"$1" "$2"; }
```